# Golang runes in string or how to convert?

Tags: string, go, decode, rune

I have a string which contains following text.

```
\xD0\xA4\xD0\xB5\xD0\xB4\xD0\xBE\xD1\x80\xD0\xBE\xD0\xB2
```

It is not a literal. In string it's stored as separate characters like this `['\','x','D','0','\','x','A','4',...]`

How to convert this string to normal characters?

Comment: This is just a regular rune literal, but clearly that's not what you're looking for. Please show some code, including desired vs actual output.

Comment: @Marc OP already provided a string. For that the outcome should be `Федоров`.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/Xb5sOLFX1vj --- given `s`, one should return `Федоров`.

Comment: Thanks @zerkms, I get that from the comments. But the question is still unclear for anyone not going through all the comments. It should be edited for future viewers.

Comment: Super quick and dirty https://play.golang.org/p/KTvTR3NAPto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go accepts hexadecimal [rune literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals).

So you can use your input as a regular string:

```
fmt.Println("\xD0\xA4\xD0\xB5\xD0\xB4\xD0\xBE\xD1\x80\xD0\xBE\xD0\xB2")
Федоров
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8y6XlK5g0MZ) example.

If you start with the actual string `["\" "x" "D" "0" ...]`, you'll need to convert the individual 4-byte sequences to characters.
One dirty way is:

```
s := `\xD0\xA4\xD0\xB5\xD0\xB4\xD0\xBE\xD1\x80\xD0\xBE\xD0\xB2`
s2, _ := hex.DecodeString(strings.Replace(s, "\\x", "", -1))
fmt.Printf("%s", s2)
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tyQPfhfKDCi) example.

Edited to answer edited question.

Comment: The string contain characters as ['\','x','D','0'... etc] and it does not recognized as runes

Comment: The code above works exactly as shown. What did you do, and what was the output?

Comment: @Marc they don't have a string literal `\xD0`, they have a string `\xD0`, effectively it would be `\\xD0` if used in a string literal.

Comment: I read file. File contain characters \xD0\xA4\xD0\xB5\xD0\xB4\xD0\xBE\xD1\x80\xD0\xBE\xD0\xB2, and want convert to Федоров

Comment: @Flimzy they say that: "I have a string which contains following text". " 
That literal string is in a file" --- literals exist only in code.

Comment: @Flimzy it does not matter where that string comes from: a network, a file or `/dev/urand`. OP provided the exact characters in a string.

Comment: I changed my question

Comment: Note that this will only work if the entire input string is hex-encoded. If it contains mixed hex-encoding and normal ASCII encoding (which is permitted by Go, but may not be by whatever the OP's input source is), this will fail.

Comment: Indeed, this is the very definition of hacky. Doing this properly would require switching on encoding prefix (if present). eg: `scanf` or regexps, but the answers should provide OP with a way to get started on more real-world scenarios.